# How to access parent object in a tree structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, uwp

I am using MVVM and it is working all fine, except one thing, accessing parent model objects.

The goal is to access any model object's parent object directly, but I could not find a propper way to do that.

For example:

Grandparents

--- Parents

--- --- Children

--- --- --- Grandchildren

I have a reference to a Child, but I have to check some properties of Children and maybe Parents.

Currently the code is running through all higher level objects until there is a successful match in the Parent's Children's Grandchildren with my Grandchild object, and then it is possible to check the properties.
But this is kind of disgusting in terms of smart code and efficiency, independent of how this is done, I do not want to run through all my data for a lucky match. This is the current imoplementation, some other parts are done by using LINQ.

```
    var someChild = calledChild;
    foreach (Grandparent gParent in mainViewModel.SelectedEnvironment.GrandParents)
    {
        foreach (Parent parent in gParent.Parents)
        {
            foreach (Child child in parent.Children)
            {
                if (child.A == calledChild.A)
                {
                     // Match
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CalledChilds grandparent is " + gParent.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The model is set up in classes with definitions like this:

```
public class Parent : ObservableObject
{
    public const string NamePropertyName = "Name";
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);
        }
    }

    public const string ChildrenPropertyName = "Children";
    private ObservableCollection<Child> _children;

    public ObservableCollection<Child> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_children == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _children = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ChildrenPropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

The model is saved in a json file and parsed back to the model's root object type for usage.

I can not just add a new reference "Parent" to the "Child" object, because it would end up in a loop, due to this concepts restrictions.

It would be great to get references instead of copies of the whole model branch.

Is there a way to access the parent objects directly?

Thank you all!

Comment: This isn't really a MVVM problem. It's a general issue when using hirachical structures. You could add a reference to the parent in each child. If you do that you can easily access properties from the parent. For example `GetParent().GetParent().property` when you have to access a property from the parent in the grandchild

Comment: Please provide some example code, that provides more details to your problem

Comment: Welcome!  Your question is essentially a  set of requirements. Any code to show?  [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to store direct reference to parent node in child nodes:

```
public class ParentNode
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChildNode> _children;
    public ParentNode()
    {
        _children = new ObservableCollection<ChildNode>();
        Children = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ChildNode>(_children);
    }
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ChildNode> Children { get; }

    public void AddChild(ChildNode item)
    {
        if (item.Parent != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Item is already added to another node");
        item.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(item);
    }
    public void RemoveChild(ChildNode item)
    {
        if (item.Parent != this) throw new InvalidOperationException("Item is not direct child of this node");
        item.Parent = null;
        _children.Remove(item);
    }
}

public class ChildNode
{
    public ParentNode Parent { get; internal set; }
}
```

just be careful, because this introduces circular references - parent references children and vice versa. It is kind of violation of DRY principle, because the shape of the tree is defined twice and you could easily get out of sync (e.g. you set `ChildNode.Parent` property to something else than the actual parent).

There are ways to workaround it, but I think you could start with this.